# Aggregating Lists of Users (Strings)

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary that looks like the following, with the key being an Integer and the value being a List of strings:

```
var x = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>;
```

I would like to see if any of those Lists match each other (without being in order) so that I can group them together in a role.

The final solution will look like

```
var y = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>
```

Where the `List<int>` is the keys from `var x`. The string key will be a machine generated string such as a guid, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can map all values to their keys and then group them by value and then apply ToDictionary, for expected result.

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>
{
    { 1, new List<string> { "Adam", "Lucie" } },
    { 2, new List<string> { "Adam", "Hannah" } },
    { 3, new List<string> { "John", "Rachel" } },
    { 4, new List<string> { "Bill", "Hannah" } },
};

var result = data.SelectMany(p => p.Value.Select(v => new {Key = p.Key, Value = v}))
        .GroupBy(o => o.Value)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(v => v.Key));

foreach (var keyValues in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValues.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", keyValues.Value));
}
```